# Error in Cambridge Large2 Template in overleaf

Tags: overleaf

I am facing an issue with the Cambridge Large2 Template. First of all, this takes a lot of time to compile and eventually runs out of compilation time. I was initially using the Tex 2023 Live version. I do not understand why the file is running out of compilation time as there were no errors. My figures are within 200kb. It would be great if anyone could let me know how to solve this.

I changed the TeX Live version to 2019(Legacy) and it seemed to compile. However, now I get a error with the xkeyval. I have attched the error message. How can I work around this?

```
Package xkeyval Error: `nopatch' undefined in families `MT'.

‪/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.sty, 2246‬
See the xkeyval package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.2246 \MT@ProcessOptionsWithKV{MT}
                                   
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.
```

Regards
Debasish

Comment: running out of time is a commercial decision not a tex one, overleaf recently reduced the time allowed per job on their free accounts, if you use a paid for account you get more time, or if you run tex locally there is no time limit at all.

Comment: Thanks. But what about the issue with xkeyval

Comment: the nopatch key is rather new in microtype. Don't use it one older tex systems.

Comment: as Ulrike says, if you choose to use an old system you need to use the options available at that time.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That helped